# How to check if all the arguments have the .txt file extension in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

I want to check if an unlimited number of arguments in the cmd have the .txt extension.
For example: myscript.bat test.txt test2.exe test3.txt should return an error message because not all of the arguments have the .txt extension.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Newbie. In order to help, please copy/paste as text into the question the commands you are trying to make work. Please have a look through the SO help information about how to ask good questions. Questions without code usually go to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty straight forward: for each argument check the extension and stop if it's a wrong one:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (%*) do (
  if /i "%%~xA" neq ".txt" (
    echo Wrong extension found
    pause
    goto :eof
  )
)
echo all of them are .txt
pause
```

Note: `an unlimited number of arguments` is relative - there is a limitation on how long a command line can be.